# Welcome page not showing, SelectDir page is showing first instead

Tags: inno-setup

I'm trying to make installer using Inno Setup.

And I want to show Welcome page first, then SelectDir.

This is `CurPageChanged` example code:

```pascal
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = wpWelcome then
  begin
    HideComponents;
    WLabel.show;
    WizardForm.NextButton.Show;
    WizardForm.NextButton.Caption := 'Configure';
  end;

  if CurPageID = wpSelectDir then
  begin
    HideComponents;

    BmpFile.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\2.bmp'));
    WizardForm.DirEdit.Show;
    WizardForm.NextButton.Show;
    WizardForm.NextButton.Caption := 'Install';
    WizardForm.DirBrowseButton.Show;
    TasksSeparateBevel.Show;
    TasksSeparateBevel2.Show;
    InstallpathLabel.Show;
    DiskSpaceLablel.Show;
    ShortcutLabel.Show;
    ShortcutCB.Show;
    CreateDLabel.Show;
  end;

  if CurPageID = wpInstalling then
  begin
    HideComponents;

    MakeSlideShow;
    TimerID := SetTimer(0, 0, 10000, WrapTimerProc(@OnTimer, 4));

    WizardForm.CancelButton.show;
    WizardForm.ProgressGauge.show;
  end;
end;
```

But the SelectDir shows first then Install. Welcome page does not show!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The Welcome page is by default skipped since [Inno Setup 5.5.7](https://jrsoftware.org/files/is5.5-whatsnew.htm#5.5.7):

> As recommended by Microsoft's desktop applications guideline, `DisableWelcomePage` now defaults to `yes`. ... The defaults in all previous versions were `no`.

To show it, you have to set:

```
[Setup]
DisableWelcomePage=no
```

---

*Thought as mentioned in the quote above, the defaults are recommended, so you should follow them.*

Comment: Thanks  For Help :D